# Retrieving values from within the $scope.$on((, function(){});

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I emitted the width and height values of a rich text editor box and  retrieved those same values in a separate file using the $scope.$on function. My question is how do i access those values outside of the function yet within the same file.

I tried using the "var" keyword before the function name and still get a **variable undefined** error.

```
//emit values    
var onResizeComplete = function() {
  scope.$broadcast('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', {
      width: scope.width,
      height: scope.height 
  });
  scope.$emit('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', { 
      width: scope.width, 
      height: scope.height
  });   
};

//retrieve values
$rootScope.$on('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', function(event, data){
  RTEboxWidth = data.width;
  var  RTEboxHeight = data.height;
});
```

neither `console.log(RTEboxWidth);` nor `console.log(RTEboxHeight);` works

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Yes, RTEboxWidth undefined

Comment: Is jQuery calling `onResizeComplete` function? Also what happens when you `console.log(data)` inside `$rootScope.on()`

Comment: @HastaTamang console.log(data) inside the $rootScope.$on() prints to the console just fine. I would simply like to acess those save values outside of the function. The 'var' keyword apparently does not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `var` statement:

```js
var onResizeComplete = function() {
scope.$broadcast('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', { width: 
scope.width, height: scope.height });
scope.$emit('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', { width: scope.width, 
height: scope.height });   
};

//retrieve values
$rootScope.$on('wesRichTextEditorResizeComplete', function(event, data){
var RTEboxWidth = data.width; // <------- missing var
var  RTEboxHeight = data.height;
});
```